# Type 1 embedded font in matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, fonts, tex

I am creating plots using matplotlib, and I want my plots to contain only Type 1 embedded fonts.  But for some of the objects, matplotlib does not give me Type 1 embedded code. When I use,

```
rc('text', usetex=True);
rc('pdf',fonttype=42);
rc('font',family="Times New Roman")
```

I get CID TrueType embeded font.

When I use

```
rc('pdf',use14corefonts= True);
rc('text', usetex=True);
```

I get Type 1 Helvetica font, but not embedded.

How can I make sure I have only Type 1 embedded code ?